# WPF&MVVM: Какое стоит указать пространство имён в классах, находящихся в папках?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пусть у нашего приложения, выполненного в соответствии с шаблоном `MVVM`, будет имя `ExampleMVVMApp`, а все `ViewModel` будут храниться в почти одноимённой папке`ViewModels`.

Если мы создадим в этой папке класс, то пространсво имён по умолчанию будет `ExampleMVVMApp.ViewModels`. Как я установил экспериментальным путём, если сделать имя `namespace ExampleMVVMApp`, то код будет работать и классы в папке будут видны для других классов на верхнем уровне.

Стоит ли так делать, избегая ещё одного пространства имён, или же следует ради технической правильности возиться с несколькими пространсвами имён?

Comment: Конечно нужно пользоваться пространствами имен. Относитесь к ним как к любым идентификаторам - именам классов, свойств, методов и т.д. Он также должны упрощать чтение кода, а не запутывать читателя.

Comment: @Андрей, ну так я могу писать `namespace ExampleMVVMApp` вместо `namespace ExampleMVVMApp.ViewModels`, или лучше так не делать?

Comment: Лучше не делать, по пространству имен читатель вашего кода определит назначение класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучший солюшн - каждый класс находится в пространстве имен, соответсвующий относительному пути до этого файла. Если класс лежит в папке `ViewModels`, то пусть и будет у него неймспейс `#AppName#.ViewModels`.

Это позволяет избежать конфликтов одинаковых имен классов.

P.S Решарпер позволяет автоматически подставить нужный неймспейс. Это очень полезно при массовом перемещении файлов либо переименовывании папки.